# Color conversion in extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs

Is there a method to convert MS Access Color codes to Hex and vice versa in extjs?
e.g.:
 - (white) 16777215 -> #FFFFFF
 - (blue)  16711680 -> #0000FF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pure js:

```
var color = 5243047;

var b = Math.floor(color / (256 * 256));
var g = Math.floor((color - b * 256 * 256) / 256);
var r = color - b  * 256 * 256 - g * 256;

console.log(r, g, b);

function rgbToHex (r, g, b) {  
    r = r.toString(16);
    g = g.toString(16);
    b = b.toString(16);

    if (r.length == 1) r = '0' + r;
    if (g.length == 1) g = '0' + g;
    if (b.length == 1) b = '0' + b;

    return (r + g + b).toUpperCase();
}

console.log(rgbToHex(r, g, b));
```

You can check here: 
http://www.endprod.com/colors/

Reverse:

```
function hexToRgb (hex) {
    var result = /^#?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i.exec(hex);
    return result ? {
        r: parseInt(result[1], 16),
        g: parseInt(result[2], 16),
        b: parseInt(result[3], 16)
    } : null;
}

const rgbToDec = (r, g, b) => (b * 2 ** 16) + (g * 2 ** 8) + r;
```

Comment: Thanks sir. extjs(sencha fiddle if possible) version please if you can.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, I have no experience with extjs. But it must be fully compatitive with pure js. Plase vote up my answer.Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently MS Access colors are in BGR format - you can convert them to hex format and put values in proper order (remember to fill missing "0" for smaller numbers)

```js
var color = 16711680;
var colorBGR = color.toString(16);
console.log("BGR:", "#" + colorBGR)
var colorRGB = colorBGR.slice(-2) + colorBGR.slice(2,4) + colorBGR.slice(0,2)
console.log("RGB:", "#" + colorRGB)
```

Alternatively you can use bit operations to get color components:

```js
var color = 5243047; // #A70050

var r,g,b;
b = (color & (255 << 16)) >> 16;
g = (color & (255 << 8)) >> 8;
r = color & 255;

console.log(r.toString(16),g.toString(16),b.toString(16))
```